# Subrings of the formal power series

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I was struggling with subrings, and I was wondering if anyone could clarify this problem for me

$S=\{a_0 + a_2x^2 + a_4x^4+\dotsm\mid a_i \in\mathbb Q\}\subset \mathbb Q[[x]]$

where $\mathbb Q$ is the field of rational numbers.

So my lecture said it is a subring iff
for all $a,b$ element of $S$ we have $a-b$ is an element of $S$, 
for all $a,b$ element of $S$ we have $a b$ is an element of $S$ .

So I believe this is not a subring because $a_0 - a_2x^2$ is not an element of $S$ but I don't know if I'm 100% right or even how to prove this, can someone please explain?

Comment: I don't get it: why do you think $\;a_0+a_2x^2\notin S\;$ , again? With $\;a_0,\,a_i\in\Bbb Q\;$ , of course.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, surely it can't be an element of S because it is not in the same format as the rest of the S, but i believe this is how i am confusing myseld

Comment: Of course it is! All the coefficients of **odd powers** of $\;x\;$ are zero, right?

Comment: @gabrielsheldon But ... $a_0+a_2x^2=a_0+a_2x^2+0\cdot x^4+0\cdot x^6+0\cdot x^8+\cdots$ - it *is* in the same format.

Comment: @user8734617 Whom are you addressing and about what?

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP, and their concern that $a_0+a_2x^2$ may not be in $S$. That is why I have not tagged anyone else.

Comment: @user8734617 Oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your set $\;S\;$ contains all the power series for which all the coefficients of **odd** powers of $\;x\;$ are zero...or in other, simpler perhaps, words: all the power series with only even powers (meaning: only the coefficients of even powers are, *perhaps*, non-zero).

1) Is the difference of two such series as above described again an element in $\;S\;$ ?

2) Is the product of two such elements as above described again an element of $\;S\;$ .

The answer for both question is **yes** ...but can you *prove this* ?

Comment: No, I still can't prove it, how do I prove whether or not it is a subring?

Comment: @gabrielsheldon Exactly as written above.

Comment: i only see === ?

Comment: @gabrielsheldon Now you don't see that anymore...

Comment: okay thank you, would u be able to do the proof for me? so i can use it as a basis for my other questions?

Comment: oh wait are we treating these as 2 separate power series?

Comment: @gabrielsheldon Which "these two" ...?

Comment: a0 - a2x^2 and S

Comment: @gabrielsheldon I honestly, and no offense intended,  think you really must go back and read carefully and deeply your notes, as I think you're not ready to cope with this kind of questions: how can you even ask whether **the set** $\;S\;$ is a power series??

Comment: Thats clearly not what i asked, thank you for the help though, but i think we both missed the point of what the other was trying to say

Comment: @gabrielsheldon Didn't you write "oh wait are we treating these as 2 separate power series"? And when I asked you "which these two?",  you replied "$\;a_0+a_2x^2\;,\;\;S\;$", so: what *exactly* did I misunderstand?

Comment: sorry i think that came across rude from me,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for the product:

The product for two formal powers series is defined as a Cauchy product.

The coefficient of  $x^n$ in the product is
$$ \sum_{i+j=n} a_i\mkern1mub_j.$$
If $i+j=n$ and $n$ is odd, can both $i$ and $j$ be even?